# Set predefined value for IBAN on stripe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I have this code:

```
....
<span id="iban" class="form-control stripe-element-container">
</span>
....
computed: {
  ...mapState('payments', ['pending']),
  ...mapGetters('payments', ['pending']),
  stripeElements() {
    return this.$stripe.elements();
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.form.iban = this.stripeElements.create('iban', this.ibanOptions());
  this.form.iban.mount('#iban');
  this.form.iban.value = 1000;
},
```

The problem is that I can't add a value for `iban`. I tried like this: `this.form.iban.value = 1000;` but is not working.

Comment: This is impossible with Stripe's IBAN element right now. The only placeholder you're currently able to set is `placeholderCountry` (see https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=iban#elements_create-options-placeholderCountry)